# Retrieving data from MongoDB using NodeJS with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Okay, so in the past few days I started messing with Node (because I think I should learn something that is actually useful and might get me a job). Right now, I know how to serve pages, basic routing and such. Nice. But I want to learn how to query databases for information.

Right now, I'm trying to build an app that serves as a webcomic website. So, in theory, the application should query the database when I type in the url `http://localhost:3000/comic/<comicid>`

I have the following code in my app.js file:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {  
    var name = getName();
    console.log(name); // this prints "undefined"

    res.render('index', {
        title: name,
        year: date.getFullYear()
    });
});

function getName(){
    db.test.find({name: "Renato"}, function(err, objs){
    var returnable_name;
        if (objs.length == 1)
        {
            returnable_name = objs[0].name;
            console.log(returnable_name); // this prints "Renato", as it should
            return returnable_name;
        }
    });
}
```

With this setup I get `console.log(getName())` to output "undefined" in the console, but I have no idea **why** it doesnt get the only element that the query can actually find in the database.

I have tried searching in SO and even for examples in Google, but no success.

How the hell am I supposed to get the parameter name from the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeJs is async. You need a callback or [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise).

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var name = '';
    getName(function(data){
        name = data;
        console.log(name);

        res.render('index', {
            title: name,
            year: date.getFullYear()
        });
    });
});

function getName(callback){
    db.test.find({name: "Renato"}, function(err, objs){
        var returnable_name;
        if (objs.length == 1)
        {
            returnable_name = objs[0].name;
            console.log(returnable_name); // this prints "Renato", as it should
            callback(returnable_name);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This works (as in the app doesn't crash, and the index page is rendered in the browser) but the title isn't set. At least not for me, in my test. The title just becomes empty, and defaults to "localhost:3000".

Comment: You have add render on the callback ?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. The code looks just like yours. Getting the information from getName, assigning it to "name" and then using it in the res.render().

Comment: Oh no, sorry! My bad. I was with res.render outside the getName call. It works.

Answer (score 1):

The `getName` function is making an asynchronous call to Mongo with `db.test.find`. You can see this by adding a `console.log` after the async function. Like this:

```
function getName(){
  db.test.find({name: "Renato"}, function(err, objs){
    var returnable_name;
    if (objs.length == 1) {
      returnable_name = objs[0].name;
      console.log(returnable_name);
      return returnable_name;
    }
  });
  console.log('test'); // <!-- Here
}
```

In all likeliness, this will output:

```
test
Renato
```

You need to provide a callback to your `getName` function.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {  
  getName(function(err, name) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: name,
        year: date.getFullYear()
    });
  })'
});

function getName(cb){
  db.test.find({name: "Renato"}, function(err, objs){
    if(err) cb(err);
    var returnable_name;
    if (objs.length == 1) {
      returnable_name = objs[0].name;
      return cb(null, returnable_name);
    } else {
      // Not sure what you want to do if there are no results
    }
  });
}
```